# Android EventBus - Unregister from a specific event

Tags: android, publish-subscribe, greenrobot-eventbus

I am using EventBus in my Android application and I am trying to unregister from a specific event while keep being registered to other events.

It looks like the unregister method only takes the subscriber as a parameter, and not also the event.

I know I could use a different instance for each event, but that's not really scalable.

I have also checked Otto but it doesn't look like you can unregister from a specific event either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There really isn't a concept of this in either library AFAIK. Just keep a `boolean isThisEventSomethingToWorryAbout` and check it in your event handler method before executing your business logic, where you toggle that `boolean` under the same conditions as to when you would unregister from this specific event.

Comment: Consider switching to `RxJava` or reactive approach in general

Answer (score 0):

You can add this method to the EventBus class:

```
/**
 * Unregisters the given subscriber from a specific event class.
 */
public synchronized void unregister(Object subscriber, Class<?> eventType) {
    List<Class<?>> subscribedTypes = typesBySubscriber.get(subscriber);
    if (subscribedTypes != null && subscribedTypes.contains(eventType)) {
        unubscribeByEventType(subscriber, eventType);
        subscribedTypes.remove(eventType);
        if (subscribedTypes.isEmpty() {
            typesBySubscriber.remove(subscriber);
        }
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "Subscriber to unregister was not registered before: " + subscriber.getClass() + " / " + eventType);
    }
}
```

This allows to unregister a specific event type like so:

```
EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this, MyEvent.class);
```

**Addendum**

I just found that there's an existing method to do exactly this although it's deprecated:

```
/**
 * @deprecated For simplification of the API, this method will be removed in the future.
 */
@Deprecated
public synchronized void unregister(Object subscriber, Class<?>... eventTypes)
```

Comment: I know about this method and I don't understand why they want to deprecate it. Because I only want to register from a specific event, I created a separate instance of EventBus for the event. I am not happy with the approach, but that will work for now.